# selecting random rows from sql without duplicating records with pagination

Tags: sql, sql-server-2017

I need to fetch random records from a table which contains large set of data without duplication when applying pagination (Don't return the rows which is already returned in previous pages).I have implemented the pagination using offset as I have included lazy loading in front end.

I have used `order by newid()` function. But with pagination records are duplicating.

So how to ensure the data uniqueness in each select when pagination applies?